# Splitting huge CSV by custom filter?

Tags: java, multithreading, parsing, batch-file, file-io

I have huge (>5GB) CSV file in format:
    username,transaction

I want to have as an output separate CSV file for each user with only all of his transactions in the same format. I have few ideas in mind, but i want to hear other ideas for effective (fast and memory efficient) implementation.

Here is what i done up to now. First test is read/process/write in single thread, second test is with many threads. Performance is not that good, so i think i'm doing something wrong. Please correct me.

```
public class BatchFileReader {


private ICsvBeanReader beanReader;
private double total;
private String[] header;
private CellProcessor[] processors;
private DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>> processor;
private boolean hasMoreRecords = true;

public BatchFileReader(String file, DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>> processor) {
    try {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(file), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
        header = CSVUtils.getHeader(beanReader.getHeader(true));
        processors = CSVUtils.getProcessors();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void read() {
    try {
        readFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (beanReader != null) {
            try {
                beanReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

private void readFile() throws IOException {
    while (hasMoreRecords) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> usersBatch = readBatch();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Reading batch for " + ((end - start) / 1000f) + " seconds.");
        total +=((end - start)/ 1000f);
        if (processor != null && !usersBatch.isEmpty()) {
            processor.transform(usersBatch);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("total = " + total);
}

private HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> readBatch() throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> users = new HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>();
    int readLoginCount = 0;
    while (readLoginCount < CONFIG.READ_BATCH_SIZE) {
        LoginDto login = beanReader.read(LoginDto.class, header, processors);
        if (login != null) {
            if (!users.containsKey(login.getUsername())) {
                List<LoginDto> logins = new LinkedList<LoginDto>();
                users.put(login.getUsername(), logins);
            }
            users.get(login.getUsername()).add(login);
            readLoginCount++;
        } else {
            hasMoreRecords = false;
            break;
        }
    }   
    return users;
}
```

}

public class BatchFileWriter {

```
private final String file;

private final List<T> processedData;

public BatchFileWriter(final String file,  List<T> processedData) {
    this.file = file;
    this.processedData = processedData;
}

public void write() {
    try {
        writeFile(file, processedData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}

private void writeFile(final String file, final List<T> processedData) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("START WRITE " + "  " + file);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (T record : processedData) {
        writer.write(record.toString());
        writer.write("\n");
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Writing in file " + file + " complete for " + ((end - start) / 1000f) + " seconds.");

}
```

}

public class LoginsTest {

```
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
private static final ExecutorService procExec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);

@Test
public void testSingleThreadCSVtoCSVSplit() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>> simpleSplitProcessor =  new DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>>() {
        @Override
        public void transform(HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> data) {
            for (String field : data.keySet()) {
                new BatchFileWriter<LoginDto>(field + ".csv", data.get(field)).write();
            }
        }

    };

    BatchFileReader reader = new BatchFileReader("loadData.csv", simpleSplitProcessor);
    reader.read();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TOTAL " + ((end - start)/ 1000f) + " seconds.");
}

@Test
public void testMultiThreadCSVtoCSVSplit() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(start);

    final DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>> simpleSplitProcessor =  new DataTransformer<HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>>>() {
        @Override
        public void transform(HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> data) {
            System.out.println("transform");
            processAsync(data);
        }
    };
    final CountDownLatch readLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        BatchFileReader reader = new BatchFileReader("loadData.csv", simpleSplitProcessor);
        reader.read();
        System.out.println("read latch count down");
        readLatch.countDown();
    }});
    System.out.println("read latch before await");
    readLatch.await();
    System.out.println("read latch after await");
    procExec.shutdown();
    executor.shutdown();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("TOTAL " + ((end - start)/ 1000f) + " seconds.");

}


private void processAsync(final HashMap<String, List<LoginDto>> data) {
    procExec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (String field : data.keySet()) {
                writeASync(field, data.get(field));
            }
        }

    });     
}

private void writeASync(final String field, final List<LoginDto> data) {
    procExec.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            new BatchFileWriter<LoginDto>(field + ".csv", data).write();    
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Why not read the file writing to a file per user?  What am I missing?

Comment: BTW many machines have more than 5 GB these days and can load it all into memory.  You might find you don't need to split it at all.  Why not process the file as it is?

Comment: Why not load the data into a database, and query the transactions instead?

Comment: Well, i read the content in batches, each batch is read line by line and decide where to put the current record. When the batch is completed i start to write asynchronously to corresponding output files.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Opening a 5GB file into memory sounds like a pretty terrible idea, at least in every scenario I can imagine.

Comment: Yep, i am looking for time and memory efficient way :)

Comment: Have a dictionary to link unique usernames to a `StreamReader`. Next, stream every line from the CSV file and use the dictionary to write to the correct files.

Comment: @DavidG Is this because you have used memory mapped files for large data collection before (as most databases do) and can think of better ways of doing it or because you just don't like it?

Comment: @user3805588 A 5 GB file can be mapped into memory in around 50 micro-seconds, the actually loading will take longer if the file is not actually in memory.  This assumes you have a 64-bit JVM of course.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be better to use unix commands to sort and then split the original file?

Something like: **cat txn.csv | sort > txn-sorted.csv**

From there get a listing of the unique usernames via grep and then grep the sorted file for each username

Comment: I have to write it in java, so basically i need to find best solution algorithm. Also, i am not sure sorting will be fast and efficient.

Comment: Are you allowed to use frameworks for this? Is this a work related task or an assignment?

Comment: I'd recommend http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/ I've used it before. I think you will need to create a custom writer that will write out to a separate file based on the username then

Answer (score 1):

If you know Camel already, I'd write a simple Camel route to:
Read line from file
Parse the line
Write to the correct output file

Its a very simple route but if you want it as fast as possible it is then trivially easy make it multithreaded

eg your route would look something like:

```
from("file:/myfile.csv")
.beanRef("lineParser")
.to("seda:internal-queue");

from("seda:internal-queue")
.concurrentConsumers(5)
.to("fileWriter");
```

If you don't know Camel then its not worth learning some this one task. However you are probably going to need to make it multithreaded to get the maximum performance. You'll have to experiment where best to put the threading as it will depend on what parts of the operation are slowest.

The multithreading will use up more memory so you'll need to balance memory efficiency against performance.

Comment: OK, here is what i did:
1. start read thread, which reads in batches
2. each batch is processed by this thread in HashMap<String, List<String> where key = username, List<String = logins for that username.
3. for each key i call java executor service which is fixed size and file writing is done in parallel for all usernames.
4. when all writes for the current batch are completed, new batch is read and everything is repeated.

Comment: I have to say that on regular PC performance is not that better, due to the IO operations. 2GB file with 1000k lines is split for 100 secs in one thread and with multi thread usage it is like 60 secods.

Comment: Depends how you look at it. 40 second improvement isn't huge but a 40% improvement sounds pretty good. You could speed it up more by reading a second batch in parallel before the first batch has finished writing. Whether that's worth the effort or not depends on just how fast you need to make it.

Comment: My bad, its 6 seconds  better not 60 :(. I am clearly doing something wrong with the multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

I would open/append a new output file for each user. If you wanted to minimize memory usage and incur more I/O overhead, you could do something like the following, though you'd probably want to use a real CSV parser like Super CSV (http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/index.html):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/my/dir/users-and-transactions.txt"));
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = s.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
    String user = tokens[0];
    String transaction = tokens[1];
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/my/dir/" + user, true));
    out.println(transaction);
    out.close();
}
s.close();
```

If you've got a reasonable amount of memory, you could create a Map of user name to OutputStream. Each time you see a user string, you could get the existing OutputStream for that user name or create a new one if none exists.

Comment: This is not very efficient because for each read you open/write/close.

Comment: Yes, that's fair enough. I was thinking of minimizing memory usage. I've edited my answer accordingly.